# How to find the name/path of a parent batch file from within another batch file RUN, but not CALLed, by the parent?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

my goal is to have a general use batch file that is able to be run by name from within another  batch file, which will then do meta/introspective things with the parent batch file that ran it. In order to do this, I'm hoping I can identify the parent from within my general use file. I'm aware I can supply the name/path of the parent alongside the command as an argument when the parent runs my file, but to prevent dishonest reporting by the parent file, for aesthetic reasons, and also in the interest of exploring the functionality of batch in general, I would like to avoid doing this and leave all identification to be done by my script, if that is possible.

I've looked into `WMIC`, and I'm sure I can get the `ParentProcessID` of my script's cmd.exe instance when it runs, but I haven't found a way to do anything useful with it. I've messed with the `(goto)` trick, and I know how to get the name/path of the parent if the parent CALLs my script, but since I'm trying to RUN it (i.e. by its bare name as a command), the `(goto)` trick also hasn't done me any good, since it seems to all be one call stack.

although anyone who messes with batch should already know what I've attempted when I say these things, in the interest of fluffing up this post's content, here's how I'll use the `(goto)` trick to inspect changes to the call stack:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: TOPLEVEL.BAT, note I'm not calling my script
"MYSCRIPT.BAT"
```

```
@ECHO OFF
:: MYSCRIPT.BAT
SETLOCAL
SET "_SELF_=%~dpnx0"
(
  (goto) 2>NUL
  ECHO this is the scope I should be in: %~dpnx0
  CALL ECHO this is the scope I would break into: %%~dpnx0
  (goto) 2>NUL

  :: define variable that will be blank while still in nested scope
  CALL SET "_COMPLETE_=%%"

  IF NOT DEFINED _COMPLETE_ (
    :: go one scope deeper and recurse
    CALL "%_SELF_%"

  ) ELSE (
    :: back to baseline
    CALL "%ComSpec%" /c
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

anyway, any wizards out there know whether this is possible or how it could be done?

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75204755/edit), and post what did you try as code until now ?

Comment: I would say, it's impossible, because if the parent don't call the *child* batch, it will simply replace the parent, there will be no information left about the parent. Executing a batch without `CALL` is more like the linux shell `exec` command.

Comment: setting `%~0` as a variable in the parent script will allow the called child scripts to know the path and name, but not sure how that will help unless the children will call the parent again. That being said, it is difficult to give a proper solution here if you don't post an example of what you intend to do. It might be a simple solution if you can post examples of your code and expected results.

Comment: PS. you cannot classify the process as a parent if the child process is not called from the parent, if you want to use it in that manner, you will have to tell the children the location of it, then you have to make it know to the children, i.e setting an environment variable with the path or by adding the path to the script to the `%path%` variable.

Answer (score -1):

When chaining batchfiles there is very little info available from previous chains.
There is however the variable %cmdcmdline%.
Depending on the way the first batchfile is started, this variable may contain the name of the first started batchfile.
If manually started from the commandline it has no usefull info, but this can be silently changed to run with cmd/c (see chain0.cmd).
If started with the **start**-command or started from **explorer** or started from commandline with **cmd/c** it will contain the name of the first started batchfile in %cmdcmdline%.

chain0.cmd

```
@echo off
cls
echo this is: %~0
echo cmdcmdline=[%cmdcmdline%]

if "%comspec%" == %cmdcmdline% cmd /c %0 & exit /b

Chain1.cmd
```

chain1.cmd

```
@echo off
echo this is: %~0
echo cmdcmdline=[%cmdcmdline%]

Chain2.cmd
```

Chain2.cmd

```
@echo off
echo this is: %~0
echo cmdcmdline=[%cmdcmdline%]

pause
```